# Shrimp in rainwater puddles

Tags: entomology, limnology

After rain, we often find shrimp-like creatures in the puddles left on our concrete patio. We have also found them in the cat's water bowl (on the same patio). They are pink in color, and around 3mm long.

The idea of shrimp on land seems absurd, but that's certainly what they look like.

We live in Okinawa, and even long-time local residents don't seem to know what they are. We're on a cliff 10 meters tall, right next to the beach.

My questions: what are they, and how do they magically appear after rain? From eggs that are lying dormant on my patio, waiting for rain??

The alleged duplicate is quite helpful. My question is slightly different because I live beachside in Okinawa, not in central Florida, and my creatures are much smaller. Probably a related species, though one that doesn't seem to be familiar to the locals.

Comment: Is there any chance you could take a good picture and add it in your post?

Comment: I thought someone would ask for a picture. I'll try next time it rains. But meanwhile, after some research, I suspect that they are some sort of amphipod. Weird that the local folks don't know about them. Maybe a new arrival in Okinawa??

Comment: or maybe water fleas...

Comment: @BryanKrause: Thanks. I saw the post you cited. My creatures are quite similar, but about half the size. Just another species, I suppose.

Comment: does any match https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/imgs/512/352/3253665/PMC3253665_ZooKeys-163-013-g017.png